# Flask API can't connect to MySQL db using Docker

Tags: python, mysql, docker, flask, docker-compose

As I run `docker-compose up --build`, the db (server_sql) starts correctly and gets ready for connections. From there, I have the below api.py quite simply initiate a connection with the db container.

However, I'm prompted with `OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host` and `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (113 No route to host)`, both coming from the 'flask_api' container. I don't understand why my api container fails to connect and thus how to fix this issue.

I've used `'host': 'db'` in api.py because the name of my 'mysql' service is 'db'.

api.py:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

config = {
        'user': 'root',
        'password': 'root',
        'host': 'db',
        'port': '3306',
        'database': 'users'
    }
connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)

...
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    container_name: server_sql
    build: db/
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'

  app:
    container_name: dashboard
    build: dashboard/
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    links:
      - api

  api:
    container_name: flask_api
    build: server/api/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    links:
      - db
```

server/api/Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["api.py"]
```

db/Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:8.0.22
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD root
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE users
RUN chmod -R 777 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
COPY scripts/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 3306
```

When running `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                                  PORTS                               NAMES
fb6da103488b        b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_api   "python3 api.py"         9 seconds ago       Restarting (1) Less than a second ago                                       flask_api
e4870a420b09        b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_db    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds                            33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_db_1
...
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                                  PORTS                               NAMES
fb6da103488b        b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_api   "python3 api.py"         15 seconds ago      Restarting (1) Less than a second ago                                       flask_api
e4870a420b09        b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_db    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds                           33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_db_1
...
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                               NAMES
fb6da103488b        b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_api   "python3 api.py"         19 seconds ago      Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp              flask_api
e4870a420b09        b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_db    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 seconds ago      Up 19 seconds           33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_db_1
...
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                               NAMES
fb6da103488b        b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_api   "python3 api.py"         25 seconds ago      Restarting (1) 5 seconds ago                                       flask_api
e4870a420b09        b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_db    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 seconds ago      Up 25 seconds                  33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   b-dev-500-lyn-5-1-cardgames_db_1
```

Error while running `docker-compose up`:

```
flask_api | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_api |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 509, in open_connection
flask_api |     self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
flask_api | OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host
flask_api | 
flask_api | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
flask_api | 
flask_api | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_api |   File "/app/api.py", line 15, in <module>
flask_api |     connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
flask_api |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
flask_api |     return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
flask_api |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
flask_api |     self.connect(**kwargs)
flask_api |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
flask_api |     self._open_connection()
flask_api |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
flask_api |     self._socket.open_connection()
flask_api |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 511, in open_connection
flask_api |     raise errors.InterfaceError(
flask_api | mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db:3306' (113 No route to host)
```

Comment: If your Flask container is still running despite the failure, can you shell into it and ping the db container?

Comment: @halfer, I've tried running the containers independently starting with the MySQL db one, then the flask api one. but I still face the same error, so I can ping the db container. What exactly can I assume from here ?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that you can't ping the container?

Comment: Well I can't ping it from my api container. But I'm not sure how to ping it thought

Comment: Once `docker-compose up` has settled down, do a `docker ps` - are both containers running?

Comment: The db one yes, the api one keeps on restarting
And I made a mistake typing "so I can ping the db container", I mean't can't

Comment: Ah, right - the restarting thing is the reason. Could you copy the output of the `ps` command, and put it into your question? That is important. Next, have a look at the rolling output of the `docker-compose up` command - are there any errors there? Put them in your question too, if there are.

Comment: Ah, just looking at your logs, it seems like the API container is crashing _because_ it can't connect. I thought it was the other way around - the database container crashed, so the API could not connect. To start with, I would wrap some sort of exception handling around your db code, so that it is still up and able to reply with an error response via HTTP.

Comment: Right so how could I do such execption handler ?

Comment: I don't know Python at all, but a quick search [gives me this](https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-exceptions-try-except/). I assume `OSError` is a trappable error. That may not be the full solution, since it still does not explain why the error happens in the first place, but I would fix that first anyway.